# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.apps'

Tags: python, django-apps

I am following the instructions of the Tech With Tim django tutorial, but when I write `python manage.py migrate` on cmd apeare the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.apps'` It's nothing wrong with the manage.py file, I am on the right directory  'C:\Users\*******\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\mysite>' what can I do to solve this problem?

here is the link to the tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxTwFMZ4r5k

Comment: You need to provide a link to the tutorial you are following. It is also useful to provide us with some code to spot bugs and such. Can't really help you out without more details.

Comment: Sure there you go

Comment: The command should be: `python manage.py migrate my_app`. Here is the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate. Did you add the app to your settings file?

Comment: yes I added the app to settings, like this `'mysite.apps.mysiteConfig',`

Comment: I realized that my files aren't at the same orther as his on the video, is it a problem?

Comment: Django has a nice tutorial for beginners: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/ That also shows you how to connect to the database. Why don't you put your code on github? This way you can point exactly to the code that is giving you trouble. Making it much more easy to help you out.